# Different representations of a generating function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I came across a lecture on generating functions which claimed:
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}$$ to be equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{-2}{k} x^k $$ to be equal to

$$1 + \frac{2}{x}+ \frac{3}{x^2}+ \frac{4}{x^3}+ \frac{5}{x^4}$$

I find this quite puzzling; the only way I can reach the 3rd expression is via
$$\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{-2}{k} (-x)^{-k} $$
which is similar to the second expression but I cannot find anything similar to the first expression that is equal to the 3rd.

Is there a way to prove the equivalency of the first three expressions?

[The video lecture](https://youtu.be/zjtxJSkjejc?t=1443), second from last identity.

Comment: Are you sure you read the expressions correctly? None of the first three functions are equal to each other.

Comment: @GregMartin; I have added the source of the video lecture

Comment: Okay, you've recorded them correctly ... but the video is just plain wrong there. The first expression is a rational function with vertical asymptotes at $x=1$, the second expression is a polynomial, and the third expression is a rational function with vertical asymptotes at $x=0$. They're simply not equal.

Comment: $1\over{(1-x)^4}$ has ordinary generating function coefficients 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84, 120, 165, 220, 286, 364, 455, 560, 680,.... OTOH, $2\over{x}$ already is not defined as power series with leading zero coefficient are not invertible. So yes I agree, there is an error if these are claimed equal.